# Invalid argument supplied for foreach php pdo in hostinger

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreach

i hope you understand my problem, i don't know to much english, but i'll try. I've a page in a hostinger and when i generate the code to show the rows, gives me this error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Connection code:

```
public static function conexion() {
    try {
        $con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=example', 'usuario', 'clave');
        return $con;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And:

```
include 'functions.php';
$con = Functions::conexion();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Products p, Prices ps, ProductsPrices pc where p.IDP=pc.IDP AND ps.ID=pc.ID ORDER BY p.IDP ASC';
foreach ($con->query($sql) as $row) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'. $row['IDP'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $row['Name'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $row['Description'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td style="color: #333;">'. $row['Price'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . '<a class="btn" href="update.php?id='.$row['IDP'].'">Edit</a>' . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
```

But when i load in localhost there is not any problem, shows the rows.

Comment: This may be a little problem with you query, have you tested it in phpMyAdmin or something like that??

Comment: the query is no the problem, as i say in the last comment, i try and shows the rows.

Answer (score 0):

That is because, you are still setting the host as

```
$con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=example', 'usuario', 'clave');
```

change host name to the hostingers provided name

```
$con = new PDO('mysql:host=hostinger_host_name;dbname=example', 'usuario', 'clave');
```

hope this helps

Comment: I know that, but i have a chart too, and it shows. I think is no the problem. anyway, thanks for you reply :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php

$sql = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM Products p, Prices ps, ProductsPrices pc where p.IDP=pc.IDP AND ps.ID=pc.ID ORDER BY p.IDP ASC'");
$sq->execute();

$results = $sql->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (count($results > 0)) {

    foreach ($con->query($sql) as $row) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['IDP'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['Name'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['Description'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td style="color: #333;">' . $row['Price'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . '<a class="btn" href="update.php?id=' . $row['IDP'] . '">Edit</a>' . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this line before foreach loop

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Products p, Prices ps, ProductsPrices pc where p.IDP=pc.IDP AND ps.ID=pc.ID ORDER BY p.IDP ASC';
$pdoStatement = $con->query($sql);
$data = $pdoStatement->fetchAll();
foreach($data as $row){
    //...
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, i try your solution and gives this: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object